# KeyError: '1' when creating a list of training data

Tags: python, image, image-processing, dataset, training-data

i have a list of image as my dataset in **trainpath** folder. Under the trainpath folder, there is 2 folders, named by the class names (0 and 1). And under each folder, there is images data. And i try to create a list of training data using that dataset.

```
code = {'distracted':0 ,'not-distracted':1}

X_train = []
y_train = []
for folder in  os.listdir(trainpath) : 
    files = gb.glob(pathname= str( trainpath +'//' + folder + '/*.jpg'))
    for file in files: 
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        image_array = cv2.resize(image , (s,s))
        X_train.append(list(image_array))
        y_train.append(code[folder])
```

But, i got this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-5016fe834a0a> in <module>()
      7         image_array = cv2.resize(image , (s,s))
      8         X_train.append(list(image_array))
----> 9         y_train.append(code[folder])

KeyError: '1'
```

Comment: What is code ? It looks like the element '1' isn't in your code object

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to include it. I just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your folder names as keys, and an empty list as value :

```
code = {'0':0 ,'1':1}
```

Comment: but if i use this, may y_train contains of [] array

Comment: Then you can just add 0 or 1